# Claim Airdrop doesn't add another claim reward value to existing value, the value will change but will add to existing reward

Tags: contract-development, tokens, airdrop

Source code link: https://github.com/BIMPFinance/ClaimAirdrop/blob/main/claimPrize.sol

This contract send token to address/addresses, and the user will redeem the airdrop token of this contract

PROBLEM: After adding or airdropping to multiple address using this function

```
function addSocial(address[] _users, uint256[] _tokens) onlyOwner public {
    require(_users.length > 0 && _users.length == _tokens.length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < _users.length; i++) {
      social[_users[i]] = _tokens[i];
    }
}
```

If user did not claim the token yet, And owner wants to add another airdop rewards, token rewards value of user will change instead of adding the new rewards to existing rewar of an user

Comment: Perhaps you want to do something like `social[_users[i]] += _tokens[i];` to increase the user tokens?

Comment: Yes thats I want to figure out